# Jagged Array & Nested For Loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays, break

I have what I thought was a very basic code example, but I can't figure out why the code never completes.  It seems to stay stuck in a loop.  This very simple code is supposed to declare and initialize a jagged array with the first row having 4 columns and the second row having 3 columns.  The code asks the user for 7 integers and prints out the result to the screen.  All of that works, but it doesn't break out of the loop unless I manually break out of it.  If the manual break is used, the correct output is not achieved.

```
public class TestCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create new scanner object
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Declare two dimentional array
        int[][] num2d = new int[4][3];
        //Declare variables
        int i;
        int j;
        //Print to screen asking for user input
        System.out.print("Enter seven numbers: ");

        //Loop through array and print the result
        for (i = 0; i < num2d.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < num2d[i].length; j++) {
                num2d[i][j] = userInput.nextInt();
                System.out.println(num2d[i][j]);
                //break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code with the break commented out, I get this result, but I have to manually stop it from running.

```
run:
Enter seven numbers: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3

1
2
3
4
1
2
3
```

When I put the break in, this is what I get.

```
run:
Enter seven numbers: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3

1
2
3
4
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

What's going on?  Why can I get the correct result with the "build successful" message without using the break?

Comment: `int[][] num2d = new int[4][3];` is NOT a jagged array, it is a 2D array with 4 rows of 3 numbers each.  Please check [@Schepo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68881974/13279831)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't loop forever: it loops 12 times, because you have declared a 4x3 array - i.e. an array sized 4 where each of the elements is an array of 3 ints.

Instead, I think you want something like this:

```
int[][] num2d = {new int[4], new int[3]};
```

Answer (score 2):

your loop runs on the "columns" of the 2d array which is 4 times and for each "column" it runs on its length which is 3. 4 times 3 is 12, and you only enter 7 numbers. the console is always waiting your input.

Comment: Thanks bunch.  That makes sense.